# Storing # as password in .env file

Tags: node.js, laravel, environment-variables

My current server password is `a123!@#ASD` but in .env file `#` is used to comment out something. So characters after # in my password are neglected and I can't connect to my server. 
Is there any escaping way in .env file so that I can use my current password.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per Laravel Documenation

> All variables in your `.env` files are parsed as strings
>
> If you need to define an environment variable with a value that
>   contains spaces, you may do so by enclosing the value in `double
>   quotes`.

"Laravel" treats `#` as comment. So if there is `space` or `#` in your password then you have to enclosed it in double quotes(`""`)

```
  DB_PASSWORD =  "a123!@#ASD"
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration

Answer (score 4):

You can use `""` like

```
"a123!@#AS"
```

Env file will support Quotes.
For more details take a look https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/beware-in-env-files

Answer (score 1):

In a scenario I have something like this with json in .env:

```
#Parsed by skiping after #: '[{"name":"dummy1",password:"Pass'
destinations=[{"name":"dummy1",password:"Pass#1234"];

#parsed to correct string : '[{"name":"dummy1",password:"Pass#1234"]'
destinations=`[{"name":"dummy1",password:"Pass#1234"]`;
```

Ref:
dotenv vesrion: 16.0.1
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

backticks are supported (BACKTICK_KEY=`This has 'single' and "double" quotes inside of it.`)